# Update package.json version using Azure Dev Ops Build pipeline

Tags: npm, azure-devops, versioning

I am trying to dynamically update a package.json as part of a CI build for publishing to an npm repository.

I am following a simple scheme of yyyymm.dd.rev to create the version number.

I have followed [npm version in Azure Dev Ops pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65266297/npm-version-in-azure-devops-pipeline/65282736).

My powershell script to update variables:

```
variables:
  major: 1
  minor: 0
  patch: 0
  rev: 0
  packageVersion: '$(major)$(minor).$(patch).$(rev)'

steps:

  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: Set SemVer values
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $year = Get-Date -Format "yyyy"
        $month = Get-Date -Format "MM"
        $day = Get-Date -Format "dd"
        $rev = Get-Date -Format "HHmm"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=major]$year"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=minor]$month"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=patch]$day"   
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=rev]$rev"
```

With the variable set - I am calling the npm version command to update the package.json

```
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: Update Version of my package
    inputs:
      command: 'custom'
      workingDir: 'libs/my-package'
      customCommand: 'version $(packageVersion) --no-git-tag-version --loglevel verbose'
```

I keep getting an npm failure.  This runs fine if I execute it locally - just on the build server do I see failure:

```
/usr/local/bin/npm --version
6.14.15
/usr/local/bin/npm config list
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.14.15 node/v14.18.1 linux x64"

; environment configs
userconfig = "/home/vsts/work/1/npm/17197.npmrc"

; node bin location = /usr/local/bin/node
; cwd = /home/vsts/work/1/s/libs/my-library
; HOME = /home/vsts
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.

**/usr/local/bin/npm version 202111.04.1901 --no-git-tag-version --loglevel verbose**
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'version',
npm verb cli   '202111.04.1901',
npm verb cli   '--no-git-tag-version',
npm verb cli   '--loglevel',
npm verb cli   'verbose'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@6.14.15
npm info using node@v14.18.1
npm ERR! npm version [<newversion> | major | minor | patch | premajor | preminor | prepatch | prerelease [--preid=<prerelease-id>] | from-git]
npm ERR! (run in package dir)
npm ERR! 'npm -v' or 'npm --version' to print npm version (6.14.15)
npm ERR! 'npm view <pkg> version' to view a package's published version
npm ERR! 'npm ls' to inspect current package/dependency versions
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
npm timing npm Completed in 117ms
npm verb code 1
##[warning]Couldn't find a debug log in the cache or working directory
##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
Finishing: Update Version of my package
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm hoping to accomplish something similar. Thanks!

Comment: nope.  but admittedly gave up on it.  I'm sure it will show up again though.  I have seen npm tools that can be used to update your repo based on comments - but that is invasive and I don't want to go down that route.  As it stands we are doing it manually.  The only other option I can thing of is the variable substitution task.  You could use that to set the value -but storing the last value is the tricky part.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually did find an answer to this problem.  Azure DevOps allows for [Running git commands in a pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

So the solution is twofold:

1. You need to provide your build permission to access your repository
2. In the pipeline I added these steps

```yaml
    steps:

    - checkout: self
      persistCredentials: true
      clean: true

    - task: Powershell@2
      displayName: Checkout Branch and Initialize Defaults
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          $branch = "$(Build.SourceBranch)" -replace "refs/heads/"
          git checkout $branch
          git config --global user.email "ci@somorg.com"
          git config --global user.name "Azure CI Build"

    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Update the package version
      condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
      inputs:
        workingDirectory: $(projectDirectory)
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          npm version patch -m "update version to %s [skip ci]" --force

    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Push Changes
      condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          git add .
          git commit -m "CI: update version [skip ci]" 
          git push
```